# Fixing '__asm' in pseudocode in IDA PRO (inconsistent fpu stack error)

Tags: ida, stack, assembly

So I was doing some REing in IDA, changed a function parameter type and suddenly my stack pointer messes up (`1025B361: inconsistent fpu stack`). Does anyone know what to look for here or how to fix it?

I tried the following:

- Undefining-redefining and changing argument types.

  Changing the `double game_time` type to `float` in pseudocode, but it won't let me (`Sorry, cannot change variable type`, because it's in use in the pseudocode).

  Changing the stack definition from `0000018C var_18C dq ?` to `dd`.

  Changing the signature of `director_debug`.

  Manually editing the HEX code from `DD 1C 24` to `D9 1C 24` (forcing m32fp).

  In order: changing the function signature, changing the stack value, undefining the calling function and redefining it as a function (code).

However, none of this helped.

Pseudocode

```
_EDX = game_time_ptr_12; //float edx@2
__asm
{
  fld     dword ptr [edx+0Ch]
  fstp    [esp+18Ch+var_18C]
}
director_debug("%3.2f: Director debug: %s.\n", *(_QWORD *)&game_time, "NORMAL MODE"); //double||__int64 game_time ST24 8@2
```

Dissassembly

```
.text:1025B35B 0 184                 mov     edx, game_time_ptr_12
.text:1025B361 0 184                 fld     dword ptr [edx+0Ch]
.text:1025B364 1 184                 push    offset aNormalMode ; "NORMAL MODE"
.text:1025B369 1 188                 sub     esp, 8
.text:1025B36C 1 190                 fstp    [esp+18Ch+var_18C] ;qword ptr [esp]
.text:1025B36F 0 190                 push    offset a3_2fDirectorDe ; "%3.2f: Director debug: %s.\n"
.text:1025B374 0 194                 call    director_debug
```

What it should become

```
game_time = *(game_time_ptr_12) + 12);
director_debug("%3.2f: Director debug: %s.\n", game_time, "NORMAL MODE");
```

Answer (score 1):

In the Disassembly view, click **"Edit → Other → Reset decompiler type information"** and then select most or all of the checkboxes and hit "Ok."

I did that to repair some register variables I accidentally combined into a double and then couldn't separate them again.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had the very same issue and I could only fix it by checking the following:

Whenever some methods returned `float` or `double`, calling methods displayed `__asm fstp` instructions instead of pseudo code assignments despite those method's stack being seemingly well defined. Additionally, `inconsistent fpu stack` is displayed in the Output window when listing these methods.

Switch to the disassembly of a messed up method. Its address line prefixes are accompanied by (what seems to be) the problematic FPU stack pointer. It will display a negative value (like `.text:0x0065789-1`) at locations it calls methods that should return `float` or `double`.

I double-checked the return types of those methods, switching them back and forth from `int` to `float`/`double`, which eventually fixed the decompilation of the calling methods again.